# How is a cross site ajax request different from a normal form post?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I've been working on an ajax-powered website and of course encountered the problem with cross site requests using ajax (I'm performing a log-in thus I need to POST to my API's endpoint). I've read up on CORS and how to respond to requests in order to allow this.

My question is: how is this ajax request any less safe and a normal (say, from a form) POST request?

Doesn't this ajax request use the same routing, HTTP methods, etc that a normal request would use? Wouldn't it's inputs need to be validated just like any request?

If I remember correctly, if I create a normal form and set the action to another site it will work. Isn't this the same that the ajax POST is doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you POST from a form, your webpage will be always redirected to whatever the POST is returning, and the user will know that an action is being done.

An AJAX request will never change your webpage (unless you do it programatically), so if you can make an AJAX request to another domain, the user could never notice that a script in the webpage is accesing other domain.

CORS exists because of [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

> prevents a malicious script on one page from obtaining access to sensitive data on another web page through that page's Document Object Model.
>
> **This mechanism bears a particular significance for modern web applications that extensively depend on HTTP cookies to maintain authenticated user sessions**

If you could make POST requests to any site using ajax then you could modify any setting in any site without the user noticing it. That would be a security issue.

Comment: So basically this is just a browser thing? Other tools such as a command-line `curl` would just work?

Comment: Yes that's right, SOP & CORS are security policies that only browsers implement. curl would just work.